# WordPress CPL using JWT Token return error

Tags: c#, wordpress, xamarin, jwt, xmlhttprequest

I have to validate the users through 2 processes. This is the first: If a valid token is returned I move on to phase 2, which is just pulling a Customers List and then correlating the username. To get the customer's ID etc. and then save it to the local storage to persist the user and allow for Simpler Order Send outs.

The Error:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

The Error is vague as all hell And I have no idea what the problem is here.

```
  class WpApiCredentials
    {
        public static string SiteUri = "http://TheSite.co.za/";
        public static string WordPressUri = $"https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/{SiteUri}/";
        public static string Username = "Name";
        public static string Password = "password";
    }


 WpApiCredentials.Username = Usernamelabel.Text;
 WpApiCredentials.Password = PasswordLabel.Text;


var client = new WordPressClient(WpApiCredentials.SiteUri);
client.AuthMethod = AuthMethod.JWT;
await client.RequestJWToken(WpApiCredentials.Username, WpApiCredentials.Password);

       
 var isValidToken = await client.IsValidJWToken();

 if (isValidToken)
            {

             await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Token Received", "Phase 1 is done ", "OK");
             Login_Phase2();
                   
            }
            else
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Empty Values", "Token not Found", "OK");
            }
```

Here's what I can find in regards to the  RequestJWToken Task

```
        [AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<RequestJWToken>d__29))]
        public Task RequestJWToken(string Username, string Password);

[Obsolete("Use JWT instead of Basic")]
        Basic,

        /// <summary>
        /// JSON Web Token Authentication method. Need configure your site with this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/
        /// </summary>
        JWT
```

The Full Error

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.12-02 14:59:18.531 I/mono-stdout(20452):   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue () [0x002b3] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 

  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue () [0x002b3] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () [0x0004c] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent () [0x00000] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 12-02 14:59:18.531 I/mono-stdout(20452):   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () [0x0004c] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, System.Boolean hasConverter) [0x0004a] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x000db] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00054] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x0002d] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSeriali

12-02 14:59:18.531 I/mono-stdout(20452):   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent () [0x00000] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 zerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <2073514815234917a5e8f91b0b239405>:0 
  at WordPressPCL.Utility.HttpHelper.PostRequest[TClass] (System.String route, System.Net.Http.HttpContent postBody, System.Boolean isAuthRequired) [0x00212] in <5cf5507fc1ef4ced882a5bb2a8a2f7af>:0 
  at WordPressPCL.WordPressClient.RequestJWToken (System.String Username, System.String Password) [0x000ba] in <5cf5507fc1ef4ced882a5bb2a8a2f7af>:0 
  at Ecombeta.Views.Login.Login_Phase1 () [0x000a1] in C:\Users\Roy\source\repos\Ecombeta\Ecombeta\Ecombeta\Views\Login.xaml.cs:100
```

The Repo Link

https://github.com/wp-net/WordPressPCL/tree/master/WordPressPCL/Client

Found the Method

```
public async Task RequestJWToken(string Username, string Password)
        {
            var route = $"{_jwtPath}token";
            var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", Username),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", Password)
                });

            (JWTUser jwtUser, HttpResponseMessage response) = await _httpHelper.PostRequest<JWTUser>(route, formContent, false).ConfigureAwait(false);
            //JWToken = jwtUser?.Token;
            _httpHelper.JWToken = jwtUser?.Token;
        }
```

Comment: What line of code does this crash and what is the exception?

Comment: await client.RequestJWToken(WpApiCredentials.Username, WpApiCredentials.Password);

Comment: Got this error now aswell 'Error getting response stream (ReadDoneAsync2): ReceiveFailure'

Comment: I'm guessing you are doing some kind of Deserialization in client.RequestJWToken(), if that's the case, this error probably means you are receiving an invalid JSON response probably as a result of an error from the server. if that's not the case you will need to post the code inside client.RequestJWToken() so we could have a better look at it

Comment: @Scarnet Ima Update with what I have and What I can find Navigating this Wrapper is horrid

Comment: @Scarnet Found the Method Question is updated

Comment: Okay, go to your HTTP helper, add a break point on line 130 copy the value of responseString and use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate the response you are receiving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Ended up being something Extremely Stupid

If you notice  public static string SiteUri = "http://TheSite.co.za/"; Doesnt have /wp-json at the end.

So Method ended up being

something like this

```
 var client = new WordPressClient("http://Your-Site/wp-json/");
            client.AuthMethod = AuthMethod.JWT;
            await client.RequestJWToken(TheUserName, ThePassword);

            var x = client;
            var isValidToken = await client.IsValidJWToken();



            WpApiCredentials.token = client.GetToken();

            if (isValidToken)
            {

                Login_Phase2();
            }
            else
            {

                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Empty Values", "Token not Found", "OK");
            }
```